# Bootstrap vertical centering in navbar issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a standard bootstrap 3 navbar that I'm trying to center a larger-than-the-navbar logo, as well as the menu. I've tried a lot of previous related SO questions, but can't find a solution that works.

I'm currently trying to give both an equal padding to make them vertically centered, and I've also tried giving the menu items a line-height, but that doesn't work as well.

Heres't what I'm currently doing:

```
.navbar-brand,
.nav {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/rhfhq33s/

Comment: You want to vertically center the logo with the menu items or with the navbar height (or both)?

Comment: @AndrewLyndem, Sorry for being unclear, I want everything to be vertically centered within the navbar with additional padding on both the top of the navbar and bottom

Comment: Check Gene's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `line-height` directly to anchor:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #menu-primary > li > a { line-height: 95px; }
}
```

I used also media rule, because i guess you don't need that `line-height` when menu is collapsed.

https://jsfiddle.net/rhfhq33s/2/

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this effects my dropdown links as well? I tried just using `#menu-primary li > a ` but that doesn't work?

Comment: @the_ should be `#menu-primary > li > a` then